# How do I also sync the web calendar feeds that are in my Gmail/Google calendar into iOS 6?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar, gmail, ios, google

I have my Google calendar syncing properly, but it doesn't bring in my web calendar feeds. For example, I have Facebook events coming into my Google calendar via web calendar feed, but those same Facebook events don't come into my iOS 6 device (iPhone 5).

Edit: I found that by going to to m.google.com/sync I could enable these settings, but it is still not working.  See image: http://screencast.com/t/AaHmxCq4DOKi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried Google again and found the answer here:  http://blog.fosketts.net/2009/06/17/subscribe-internet-calendars-iphone-30/

Basically need to go into Settings > Mail,Contacts,Calendars > Add Account > Other > Add Subscribed Calendar > Paste link.

An easier way is to email yourself the links, and when you tap on them, your phone will ask you if you want to subscribe to the calendar without having to go through the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

How do you sync Google calendar on your iPhone? Is it a CalDav account or Exchange?

I've got several calendars on Google which sync without any problems using Google's exchange server. But I'm not sure if it also works with CalDav. See this page on how to set up Google exchange on your iPhone: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740